# Check input for special characters

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm writing a script which creates an apache and nginx vhost. The host name is typed from keyboard. How can i check my input and print an error message (stop script eventually) if input contains symbols: "-",","??

Comment: How are you reading the input? Have you tried anything for this yet?

Comment: I just use `read filename` and wondering will the `case` operators do for me with pattern like `case $filename in *[_]* ) do`

Answer (score 2):

A typical "read again" loop looks like this:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Hostname?" -r hostname
    case $hostname in
      *[-,]*) echo "Try again";;
      *) break;;
    esac
done
```

It's not clear to me how comma and hyphen are "special" whereas percent sign, [PILE OF POO](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm), and all the others are not.